# In magento 2 How to redirect after checkout to a link and done payment and land on sucess page

Tags: php, api, redirect, payment-gateway, magento2

In magento2, How to redirect after checkout to a link and do payment and land on success page if payment success. if payment failed or cancelled then it will land on failure or cancel page. I am new to Magneto and I'm working on magento2 to develop payment gateway.I'am stuck on front end.When user select PLACE ORDER then it post all data to particular link after transaction done it will land on magento2 page. Please suggest no official doc for magento2.

Comment: Any updates for the above post ....?

Comment: Ayush, could you finally figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

i found this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2241

it says that the redirection should be implemented client-side so what you need to do is

- create a config provider to load the destination url
- bind the "proceed" button of your payment method to some custom redirect action
- implement the redirect action via js, using the config provider

look at the paypal express implementation for details, this can be found here: [Paypal Express JS](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal-express-abstract.js#L72)